# Unused bits in pointer (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, pointers, box2d

Box2d objects have a 
`void* m_userData`
field where the user can store data. Typically you store a pointer to another object, for instance a pointer to a sprite that shall be updated with location information every system tick.

I want to store a pointer to another object, but I would be glad if I also could store one extra bit of information. Can I do that in the most significant bit of the pointer? Could the most significant bit of an object pointer be set? I mean the internal memory is only 512 MB (I guess).

Maybe the app be rejected because of this? It's not completely future proof, and it's a bit of a hack...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pointer to 'another object' can be whatever you like, so the typical way to do this would be to make a struct/class to hold whatever you want to store in the user data, eg:

```
struct myUserData {

    Object* anObject;
    AnotherObject* anotherObject;
    bool oneExtraBit;//okay, 8 extra bits :)

}
```

Then you would set one of these as the user data...

```
myUserData* mud = new myUserData;
mud->anObject = ...;
mud->oneExtraBit = ...;
myBody->SetUserData( mud );
```

Comment: Yes, that is of cause the most structured solution. I keep this question open though, because I want to get an answer to the bit in pointer question.

Thanks anyway!